# Did Socrates say “The secret of change is..."?

Tags: history, quotes

> The secret of change is to focus all of your energy, not on fighting the old, but on building the new.

Did Socrates say this ?

Comment: Socrates (or Aristotle.. or Kant or Hegel or Aquinas or ... etc) would never write or say a sentence that begins with "The secret of change is"... -regardless of what follows. Perhaps, at most, when drunk.

Answer (score 9):

No, he didn't. At least not the Socrates of ancient Greece.
According to [Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Socrates#Misattributed):

> The secret of change is to focus all of your energy, not on fighting the old, but on building the new.
>   This a actually a quote from a character named Socrates in [Way of the Peaceful Warrior: A Book that Changes Lives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_of_the_Peaceful_Warrior), by Dan Millman.